# Multidimensional array push(array) not working ERROR: undefined reading ('0') - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code, everything works fine until the last `else if`, the `vector` variable  works fine and gots the expected data in it, but when I try to push it to `vectorvalores` it gives me this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`.

I need to create a new row in vectorvalores if the expected name wasnt already in the table (names go in `vectorvalores[j][0]`). Should I do it with objects instead of arrays?

I'm not a programmer I'm doing this for a finance google sheet just as a hobby, so probably the code has to be optimized in most of it's parts. But, I'd be happy just for it to work

```
function preciomedio(){
var hojas = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var situacioninversiones = hojas.getSheetByName('Situación de inversiones');
var historicoinversiones = hojas.getSheetByName('Histórico Inversiones');
var datos = historicoinversiones.getDataRange().getValues();
var vectorvalores = [];
var longitudvector = 9;
var estaba = false;
var averageprice = 0;
var numeroacciones = 0;
var numeroaccionesa = 0;
var averagepricea = 0;

for (var j=1;j<datos.length;j++){
  for(var i=0;i<longitudvector+1;i++){
    if(vectorvalores.length != 0){
      if(datos[j][3]==vectorvalores[i][0]){
               if(datos[j][0]=='Compra'){
        numeroacciones=numeroaccionesa+datos[j][5];
        averageprice=(averagepricea*numeroaccionesa+datos[j][6])/numeroacciones;
        numeroaccionesa=numeroacciones;
        averagepricea=averageprice;
       }
       else if(datos[j][0]='Venta'){
       numeroacciones=numeroaccionesa-datos[j][5];
       }
       estaba = true;
       vectorvalores[i][1] = numeroacciones;
       vectorvalores[i][2] = averageprice;
      }
    }
  }
  if(estaba == true) {
    estaba = false;
  }
  else if(estaba == false){
    var a = datos[j][3];
    var b = datos[j][5];
    var c = datos[j][6];
    var vector = [a,b,c];
    vectorvalores.push(vector);
    historicoinversiones.getRange(j,15).setValue(vector[0]);
    longitudvector += 1;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Mhh don't know but `historicoinversiones.getRange(j,15).setValue(a)` is the same right?

Comment: Welcome. In all likelihood the error relates to an index value in one of the `for` statements. Since we don't have any data, I suggest that you do some trouble shooting: track the instances of `i` and `j` by inserting some `Logger.log("i: "+i)` and `Logger.log("j: "+j)` or `Logger.log("i: "+i+", j: "+j)`statements and look at the Execution Log to see if/when `j` exceeds the quantity of data.

Comment: @Tedinoz the for loops are working, the last part `historicoinversiones.getRange(j,15).setValue(vector[0])` prints the expected results in the sheet, so we can say `i` and `j` do work well.

Comment: @RemcoE33 `historicoinversiones.getRange(j,15).setValue(vector[0])` it's just there for testing if the for loops where working, is not expected to be there.

Comment: So, the problem comes from `if(datos[j][3]==vectorvalores[i][0])` I dont know why cuz the `vectorvalores[0][0]` has data in it after the first loop (which doesnt generate the error)

Comment: @colo then create a [sample](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) sheet with the (redacted) input data and the script.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the answer to my problem, first of all `var longitudvector = 9;` should be `var longitudvector = 0;`

Another problem was  `else if(datos[j][0]='Venta'){` was missing a `=`.

After that I just had to adjust some of the for loops, and now it's working perfectly.